# Cannot find JHipster's mvn command with container

Tags: maven, jhipster

I'm using Bitbucket's Pipelines to automate my deployments. I am working on an Angular Project but use Maven to deploy my artifacts.

I was looking around to find a Docker container that contained both npm and maven and came across jhipster (v3.7.1). After installing, I cannot run "mvn" or "./mvnw" in any way. It says the command cannot be found.

Suggestions appreciated. In the meantime, I'm using pbarnoux/maven-angular and this container works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a closer look at the  [jhipster dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster/~/dockerfile/) you can see that maven is not installed i.e. the command is not available and your information that mvn cannot be run is correct. As a solution you cold add the maven at a package to all the other utilities to be installed:

```
# install utilities apt-get install -y \
                         maven \ 
                         wget \ 
                         curl \
                         vim \ 
                         git \ 
                         zip \ 
                         bzip2 \ 
                         fontconfig \ 
                         python \ 
                         g++ \ 
                         build-essential && \
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This is my first foray into Dockerland. Cheers!